# Is email required for Firebase Authentication?

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm making a tiny app for a few people. Since they all have iPhones and I need some low-key user management, I'm going to use Firebase. It has a really easy-to-use implementation of "Sign in with Apple", which is just what I need.

As far as I can tell, "Sign in with Apple" natively lets you specify requested scopes like this (when implementing it yourself):

```
request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
```

But I don't need their email. I just want a unique user (by some hidden ID), and their name (not necessarily unique).

When using Firebase, following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui), I don't have access to the "request" or its scope, and it seems like email is requested by default. Is `.email` required for Firebase in this case? It seems so, as when using it now, I see that the user email is used as "Identifier" in the user list in the Firebase Authentication console.

If so, it's not a deal-breaker for me (though I'm sure it is for some), but it does feel "iffy" requesting their e-mail adresses for literally nothing.

Is it possible to use "Sign in with Apple" in Firebase without requesting the users email?

Comment: Email is not a required field.  What happens if you simply remove that scope? That should answer your question.

Comment: @DougStevenson My bad, poorly written question. When using Firebase's UI, I don't have access to that line of code. I can't specify the scope. That line of code is part of Apple's native `AuthenticationServices`, when implementing it manually. Since I'm using FirebaseUI, I don't have access to the requested scopes (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

After going into the FirebaseUI-files (from CocoaPods) and changing a few fields, it does work perfectly without email. The users simply show up with "-" as identifier in the console.

The only file I needed to change was `FUIOAuth.m`, by removing the scope "email" from lines `:195` and `:245`.
This is obviously a terrible idea. Never edit pods. But now I know that it is possible.
I could download the framework as a zip and do my changes there if I really want the FirebaseUI, or I can just ditch the entire FirebaseUI and create my own UI and implement it without the email-scope.

If only they could expose the scopes so I didn't have to do either of these..